# extraction of CIFAR-10 database

Tags: database, extract

I am trying to extract CIFAR 10 database by using this code but I am getting following error please help me to remove this error.

Is there any other way to extract this database. I tried to solve this error but I unable to do it. please help me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import os
def unpickle(file):
    if os.path.getsize(file) > 0: 
    # load files from dict
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
            data = pickle.load(f, encoding='bytes')
        return data


def load_cifar10_data(data_dir):
    #Return train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels
    train_data = None
    train_labels = []

    for i in range(1, 6):
        data_dic = unpickle(data_dir + "/data_batch_{}".format(i))
    if i == 1:
        train_data = data_dic['data']
    else:
        train_data = np.vstack((train_data, data_dic['data']))

    train_labels += data_dic['labels']

    test_data_dic = unpickle(data_dir + "/test_batch")
    test_data = test_data_dic['data']
    test_labels = test_data_dic['labels']

    train_data = train_data.reshape((len(train_data), 3, 32, 32))
    train_data = np.rollaxis(train_data, 1, 4)
    train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

    test_data = test_data.reshape((len(test_data), 3, 32, 32))
    test_data = np.rollaxis(test_data, 1, 4)
    test_labels = np.array(test_labels)

    return train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels

data_dir = 'D:\Database\cifar-10-batches-py'

train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels = load_cifar10_data(data_dir)

print(train_data.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

print(test_data.shape)
print(test_labels.shape)

# In order to check where the data shows an image correctly
plt.imshow(train_data[2])
plt.show()
```

error:

> File "D:/Program files/Spyder files/deep learning/untitled6.py", line
>   37, 
>       in load_cifar10_data
>       train_data = np.vstack((train_data, data_dic['data']))
>
> ```
> KeyError: 'data'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer so late, but use `data_dic[b'data']` and `data_dic[b'labels']` since it's in byte format.